# A generic error Occurred in GDI+ ( only on Azure server)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure-web-app-service

I am deploying the below code in AZURE:

```
string filePath = "~/Templates/Work/Template.docx";
using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    SaveToStream(stream, FileFormat.Docx);
    Document finalDoc = new Document();
    finalDoc.LoadFromStream(stream, FileFormat.Docx);
    stream.SetLength(0); 
    finalDoc.UpdateTableOfContents();
    finalDoc.SaveToStream(stream, FileFormat.Docx);
    return stream.ToArray();
}
```

This is my code. Its working fine in my local machine. But its throwing an error in azure server:

> A generic error Occurred in GDI+

Comment: string filePath = "~/Templates/Work/Template.docx";
using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
{
SaveToStream(stream, FileFormat.Docx);
Document finalDoc = new Document();
finalDoc.LoadFromStream(stream, FileFormat.Docx);
stream.SetLength(0);
finalDoc.UpdateTableOfContents();
finalDoc.SaveToStream(stream, FileFormat.Docx);
return stream.ToArray();
}
}

Answer (score 0):

Win32k.sys (User32/GDI32) Restrictions
For the sake of radical attack surface area reduction, the sandbox prevents almost all of the Win32k.sys APIs from being called, which practically means that most of User32/GDI32 system calls are blocked. For most applications this is not an issue since most Azure Web Apps do not require access to Windows UI functionality (they are web applications after all).

https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox

Comment: Interesting though, that the used docx Document API uses that internally

Comment: what is the solution. Do I need to change the code ?

Comment: yes, there is no solution. you could try to upgrade to standard tier of the webapp (just read the article I've linked). If that doesnt help - change the code

Comment: that link is not opening in my office. if the case to change the code, what is the problem in current code.?

Comment: i have red the link. it says, they gave fix in spire.doc version 6.0. I tried with that dll. even though am getting same error.